# Find the minimum value of '$n$ for which $\frac{(2i)^n}{(1+i)^{n-2}}$ is positive integer.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the minimum value of $n$ for which $\dfrac{(2i)^n}{(1+i)^{n-2}}$ is positive integer.

I tried solving this question and simplified the given expression to get, $(\sqrt2)^{n+2}\left\{-\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{4} \right)+i \cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{4} \right)\right\}$.

Now, I think for this expression to be positive integer, imaginary part of the complex number must be $0$. So...

$$\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{4} \right) = 0 \implies \dfrac{n\pi}{4} \equiv k \pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2}\ {\rm{Where}}\ k \in \mathbb{Z}  $$

How to solve it further? There is no such restriction that $n$ must be positive.

Comment: Hint: The factor of $2\sqrt{2}^n$ out front is not there for show. What happens with excessively negative values of $n$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi ohh yeah I didn't notice that. Thank you man, you are great!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}\frac{(2i)^n}{(1+i)^{n-2}}&=(2i)^2\left(\frac{2i}{1+i}\right)^{n-2}\\&=-4(1+i)^{n-2}\\&=-4\sqrt2^{\,n-2}\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)i\right)^{n-2}\\&=-4\sqrt2^{\,n-2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)+\sin\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)i\right).\end{align}So, you're after the smallest $n$ such that $\cos\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)<0$ and that $\sin\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)=0$. And then $n=6$ is the answer. You also have $\sin\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)=0$ when $n=2$, but then $\cos\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}4\right)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can also resolve the question without applying deMoivre's Theorem.  Noting in advance that $ \ (1 + i)^2 \ = \  2i \ \ , \ $ we can write
$$ \frac{(2i)^n}{(1 \ + \ i)^{n-2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{(2i)^n}{(1 \ + \ i)^n} ·(1 \ + \ i)^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{(2i)^n}{[ \ (1 \ + \ i)^2\ ]^{n/2}} ·(2i) \ \ = \ \ \frac{(2i)^{n \ + \ 1}}{ (2i)^{n/2}} \ \ = \ \  (2i)^{(n/2) \ + \ 1} \ \ . $$

For $ \ n \ \in \ \mathbb{N} \ \ , \ $ the factor $ \ i^{(n/2) \ + \ 1} \ $ is  $ \ +1 \ $ only for $ \ \frac{n}{2} + 1 \ = \ 4k \ \ , \ \ k \ \in \ \mathbb{N} \ \ , \ $ so our ratio is only equal to a positive integer for $ \ n \ = \ 8k - 2 \ \ . \ $  So the smallest permissible values are $ \ k \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ n \ = \ 6 \ \  $ (for which the ratio equals $ \ 16 \ \ . \ ) $

You would be correct about there being no minimum *integer*  $ \ n \ $ for the problem as you show it:  presumably, it is intended that $ \ n \ $ be a *positive* integer (natural number).